# What packages are required for KDE Plasma widget development on Kubuntu?

Tags: kde-plasma, ubuntu

I'd like to develop a KDE Plasma widget, but the developer guide tells me to fetch "KDE Trunk" to get started. I have three problems with that:

- I'd rather not get the whole source code of KDE just to develop a simple widget.
- I want to develop a widget for the current version (10.10) of Kubuntu. Guess a tag would do, but what about Kubuntu's patches?
- KDE seems to be in the middle of moving from Subversion to Git, so "KDE Trunk" (i.e. SVN) doesn't seem to be sufficient, and mixing Git and Subversion repositories doesn't sound good.

I've spotted quite a few KDE packages ending in *-dev*, so I guess some of those will be all I need.

Which packages in particular do I need to install in order to compile a Plasma widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's described here:
http://techbase.kde.org/Getting_Started/Build